# MySQL Query Two (COUNT)

Tags: mysql

I'm experiencing a little trouble with COUNT.
I need to count files and folders onto a storage. Here my structure.

```
DATABASE

STORAGE
  storage_id    storage_name
  1             SERVER 01


FOLDERS
  folder_id   folder_storage_id   folder_name
  1           1                   EXAMPLE FOLDER 

FILES
  file_id    file_folder_id    file_name
  1          1                 test.pdf
  2          1                 test2.pdf
  3          1                 test3.pdf
  4          1                 test4.pdf


QUERY

SELECT  *,

folder_storage_id AS folder_id, COUNT(*) AS folder_qty,

file_folder_id AS file_id, COUNT(*) AS files_qty

FROM
files

LEFT JOIN
folders ON folder_id = file_folder_id

LEFT JOIN
storage ON storage_id = folder_storage_id
```

I receive same value (4) for $folder_qty and $files_qty

EXPECTED

($folder_qty) 1

($files_qty ) 4

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
   COUNT(DISTINCT folder_storage_id) AS folder_qty,
   COUNT(*) AS files_qty
FROM
   files
LEFT JOIN
   folders ON folder_id = file_folder_id
LEFT JOIN
   storage ON storage_id = folder_storage_id
WHERE 
   storage_id = ?
```

It doesn't make much sense to select any other columns, since aggregation is performed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT

COUNT(DISTINCT file_folder_id) as folder_qty,
COUNT(file_id) as files_qty

FROM
storage s
LEFT JOIN folders d ON s.storage_id = d.folder_storage_id
LEFT JOIN files f ON d.folder_id = f.file_folder_id

WHERE s.storage_id = 1
```

Comment: Answer by Giorgos Betsos will work if you change COUNT(DISTINCT folder_storage_id) for COUNT(DISTINCT folder_id)

Comment: Answer by Darshan Mehta will work if you change count(fo.folder_id) for count(distinct fo.folder_id)

Answer (score 0):

To count number of folder ids and file ids for storage, we can use `group by` clause with `count()` aggregate function for both folder id and file id; try the following query:

```
select s.storage_id, count(fo.folder_id), count(fi.file_id)
from storage s left join folders fo on s.storage_id = fo.folder_storage_id
left join files fi on fo.folder_id = fi.file_folder_id
group by s.storage_id;
```